# Javascript- Using CSS opacity information

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm puzzled about getting a simple toggle to work that should be fairly simple. I want the div to fade out when the opacity is 100 and fade in when it is 0. http://jsfiddle.net/mGdcm/8/

Javascript-

```
$('#toggleButton').click(function() {
if ($('#toggleSection').css("opacity") === 0) {
    $('#toggleSection').fadeIn("slow");
}
else {
    $('#toggleSection').fadeOut("slow");
}
return false;
});
```

HTML-

```
<a href="#" id="toggleButton">toggle</a>
    <div id="toggleSection" style="opacity:0;"> <p>Why isn't this working?</p></div>
```

Comment: `.css("opacity")` returns a string, so you'd need `=== "0"` or `== 0`. And you'd need `.fadeTo("slow", 1)` since you're not setting the `display` css property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the jQuery [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) function.

```
$('#toggleButton').click(function() {
    $("#toggleSection").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mGdcm/16/

Comment: +1 learned something new (`fadeToggle`).  Nice.  New in jQuery 1.4.4 I just read. :)

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible for the fadeToggle to work when the opacity starts at 0? I think that is my major source of difficulty.

Comment: @user998266: You'd need to set `display:none` if that works with your design. If not, use `.fadeTo("slow", 1)` and `.fadeTo("slow", 0)` instead of `fadeIn/fadeOut`. [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/c7v28/). [Or this](http://jsfiddle.net/c7v28/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set jQuery in your fiddle, not MooTools. :)

Also for fading back in, check that the css `display` property is equal to "none".

Fixed version for you at http://jsfiddle.net/mGdcm/14/.

Comment: AH thanks! But it seems to still not work if I set it to jQuery. Is it working for you?

Comment: It fades out fine, but it does not fade back in, because fadeOut takes the opacity down to zero THEN sets display to none. Working on it.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Do you know of a way to make this toggle work if the div starts at opacity:0?

Comment: Interesting problem.  I got it to work with `fadeTo` (http://jsfiddle.net/mGdcm/24/) but not with `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jQuery, and the correct code using [**visible selector**](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

```
$('#toggleButton').click(function() {
    if ($('#toggleSection:visible').length < 1) {
        $('#toggleSection').fadeIn("slow");
    }
    else {
        $('#toggleSection').fadeOut("slow");
    }
    return false;
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/mGdcm/13/)

---

[**Example starting with not visible**](http://jsfiddle.net/mGdcm/19/)

Comment: Thank you! Could you please post an updated jfiddle where you have it working? I pasted that code and ran it with jQuery but the toggle did not work. Do I need to change something in the HTML?

Comment: on the left side of jsfiddle, do you see Choose Framework and underneath that MooTools?

Comment: Thank you for the example! Is there a way to make it work so that the div starts out with opacity:0?

Comment: `style="display:none;"` instead of `style="opacity: 0"`

Answer (score 0):

Not a very good solution but it works :)

```
$('#toggleButton').click(function() {
    console.log($('#toggleSection').css("opacity"));
    if ($('#toggleSection').css("opacity") == 0) {
        $('#toggleSection').fadeIn("slow", function(){
            $('#toggleSection').css("opacity", 1);
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#toggleSection').fadeOut("slow", function(){
            $('#toggleSection').css("opacity", 0);
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```